# verbatim mode and carriage return character tokens

Tags: tex-core, verbatim, catcodes

This question refers to how the program TeX creates tokens after reading a line of a .tex-file. It does actually not refer to writing macros or doing typesetting work which takes place in stages after tokenization.

Assume TeX is switched to verbatim catcode régime, where `^^`-notation and the like doesn't work.

(Verbatim catcode régime: `␣`(space), `\`, `{`, `}`, `$`, `&`, `#`, `^`, `_`, `%` and `~` all have category code 12 assigned, which is "other". No character has assigned one of the category codes 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 10, 14 and the only character that might be active or might have category 5 is the carriage return character, which might also have one of the categories 9, 11, 12 and 15.)

Can TeX, while such a catcode régime is in effect, produce—by reading lines from a .tex-file and tokenizing characters of that line— an explicit character token whose character code is 13?
(Character code 13 in TeX's internal character encoding scheme denotes a character which also is referred to as "carriage return character" or CR. So let's name such tokens explicit carriage-return-character-tokens.)

---

(Edit: This question is motivated by attempts of grasping why with LaTeX's verbatim environments and arguments of type `+v` relying on explicit carriage-return-character tokens as markers for places where in the corresponding .tex-input file a line ended, is safe. Seems it is safe because in verbatim mode such character tokens cannot come into being during tokenization other than due to the `\endlinechar`-mechanism. )

Comment: @DavidCarlisle TeX could be switched to verbatim catcode régime by a macro which does a lot of reading and tokenizing and under certain conditions, e.g., having encountered characters that form a specific phrase, switching back to normal caatcode-régime. Seems, this is the underlying idea with LaTeX's `\verb` and verbatim-environments that scan for an ending-phrase tokenized in verbatim catcode régime...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle If you combine a verbatim catcode régime where the carriage return character is assigned category 12 while `\endlinechar` is 13, characters inserted due to the endlinechar-mechanism get tokenized as explicit character tokens of category 12(other)...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle If I understand correctly, then "might" indicates that it also might not be active. Probably the questioner is willing to clarify what "might" might mean... ;-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle "the only character that might be active or might have category 5 is the carriage return character": No character other than the carriage return character might have one of these categories. The carriage return character is the only character that might have one of these categories. It might also have one of the categories 9, 11, 12 and 15.

Comment: @Cattleya you clearly have some processing setup in mind your question would be _a  lot_ clearer if you included an example input and then asked if that could produce active ^^M  as it is, I really can not even guess what this question means

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Where did I state that ends of lines are character 13? I stated: "Character code 13 in TeX denotes the carriage return character." I did not state that the carriage return character denotedd by character code 13 always is what TeX appends to characters of a line.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle TeX's internal character representation scheme is ASCII or unicode. Code point  number 13 in these encodings encodes the carriage return character. So character code 13 in TeX('s internal character encoding scheme) denotes the carriage return character. It is not necessarily considered to be printable. What you get when an explicit carriage-return-character-token of category 11 or 12 in TeX makes it into typesetting glyphs in boxes depends on the font encoding.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Tell Donald Knuth who in his TeXbook explained that the internal character encoding scheme allows 256 characters, the character codes of characters 0-127 complying to ASCII where code point 13 encodes the carriage return character. I did not use the word "represent", I just gave the name of that character. I did not ask about glyphs of whatsoever fonts. I precisely and clearly asked about producing explicit character tokens, no matter how those subsequently would be processed, the processing probably leading to typesetting something.

Comment: you used the word "denotes" rather than "represents" but I can't see any interpretation of tex's implementation where that is true.  Sorry I'm not trying to be argumentative I was just trying to prod you into editing the question so that it was possible to at least guess what was intended but it seems that's not possible, I voted to close as unclear, and have cleaned up most of the comments.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle How can you get it mid line in verbatim mode? According to what Ulrich Diez wrote, TeX's routines for reading a line of a text file don't take a carriage return character for something that can be mid-line and ^^-notation in verbatim mode is ruled out. But yes, `\endlinechar` must be 13 - this is what I indicated by "Seems it is safe because in verbatim mode such character tokens cannot come into being during tokenization other than due to the \endlinechar-mechanism."

Comment: ah I meant in general not if you have no ^^ (I deleted that comment to avoid confusion) . It would of course be compliant for a tex system just to use native end of line, so #10 on linux and then #13 would appear mid-line, but all web2c based system (and miktex) treat #10, #13 and #13#10 pairs as end of line on all platforms

Comment: So verbatim environments are not totally safe in TeX implementations where only linefeed or carriage return paired with linefeed is accepted as marker for the end of a line of text?

Comment: @Cattleya Nothing is safe in TeX.

Comment: @Cattleya "According to what Ulrich Diez wrote, TeX's routines for reading a line of a text file don't take a carriage return character for something that can be mid-line " Perhaps Ulrich Diez should have noted that the author of the initial release of his answer only knows web2c based implementations. ;-)

Comment: @Cattleya tex is designed to work with record based systems where there is no native concept of an end of line character files are simply a stack of records (think a box of punched cards) even by the time 2e was launched we had to deal with systems that had no directory structure or allowed no file extensions, the modern convergence in tex of assuming `/` separates paths and `.` may be used to append `sty` makes everything seem a lot more regular than it was (look at my comments from 30 years ago in ltdircheck.dtx :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(This answer does not take the possibilities of the Lua-backend of a LuaTeX-engine into account.)

Simplified speaking:

With the TeX implementations known to the author of the initial release of this answer<sup>1</sup>, the routines for reading a line from a text file (beneath other things) don't take carriage return characters occurring in a text file for something that belongs to the characters written "into" a line of text. But the routines for reading a line from a text file take carriage return characters occurring in the text file for something that denotes that subsequent stuff in the text file belongs to subsequent lines of the text file.

Thus, with the TeX implementations known to the author of the initial release of this answer, carriage return characters occurring in a text file don't make it into what, after reading a line from a text file, by TeX is processed as "the characters of the line of the text file" while characters of the text file that during reading from the text file don't make it into what is considered "the characters of the line of the text file" are not subject to treatment during tokenization.

With the TeX implementations known to the author of the initial release of this answer, in the context of reading text files, only two possibilities are known to the author of the initial release of this answer, how the circumstance of a carriage return character being subject to treatment during tokenization can come into being:

Possibility 1:
Right after reading a line of a text file, within in the stage of pre-processing the characters of that line, where the category code régime is not yet effective, TeX's `\endlinechar`-mechanism may have caused the appending of a carriage return character to "the characters of the line of the text file". That carriage return character is subject to treatment during tokenization and hereby is treated according to the catcode régime current at the time of treating.
(With catcode régimes where `^^`-notation is not possible, this is the only possibility of how the circumstance of a carriage return character being subject to treatment during tokenization can come into being.)

Possibility 2:
With catcode régimes where `^^`-notation is possible, the circumstance of a carriage return character being subject to treatment during tokenization can come into being during the stage of tokenization, i.e., after pre-processing, due to encountering the carriage return character's `^^`-representation, i.e. `^^M` or `^^0d`, and replacing the characters forming that `^^`-representation by a carriage return character and subsequently treating that carriage return character according to the catcode régime current at the time of treating.

So, with the TeX implementations known to the author of the initial release of this answer, the circumstance of a carriage return character being subject to treatment during tokenization is never due to TeX having found it in what, right after reading a line of a text file, TeX considers the characters of that line of the text file.

----
<sup>1</sup>The author of the initial release of this answer only knows web2c implementations of TeX where ⟨linefeed⟩ and ⟨carriage return⟩ and ⟨carriage return⟩⟨linefeed⟩ are treated as line ends.